# Linux read dilemma

Tags: c++, linux, c++17, fifo

I need to read from a fifo. Using `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`, I faced the following situation.

When a large set of data must be read from fifo, I get the Returned (i.e. `ssize_t`) `-1`, and `errno == 11`, meaning "device is busy".

After writing the code to handle that, I tried something which sends a small amount of data to fifo. In this case, after the first read I still get Returned == `-1` and `errno == 11`. Well, somehow the OS must differentiate between "no data available", and "device being busy". Either set Returned to 0, or change errno.

The only other thing to do is to see if read() returned fewer than count. But what will happen if the last read was so that " Returned == count"? That will result in an infinite loop of checking for errno 11, and trying again.

Is there a better solution to this?

The language used is C++.

Comment: Could you include a [mcve], including code that writes to the fifo as well as the code that reads it?  The expected behavior depends on the exact sequence of open/read/write/close on both ends, as well as whether the fd is opened blocking or non-blocking.

Comment: Also, when mentioning `errno` values, it would be best to use the symbolic `E****` name, like `EBUSY`; these have a standard meaning between platforms and programmers can recognize them more easily.  The numerical values can vary between platforms and I don't think most people have them memorized.  So is it in fact `EBUSY` that you mean here?

Comment: Thank you. I now use sensing end of input from a marking, so I have a solution. I believe it is EBUSY,  the actual message is: "Resource temporarily unavailable". I really do not know the actual symbol. Well, the minimal code you want will take time that I do not have. The description should be clear. You can assume the sequence is correct. After all now it all works. So, the dilemma remains the same: i.e. whether there is no more data available, or fifo has not received all data yet, you will get the same from Linux. That is the point of my question, not the actual code. Thank you Sir.

Comment: "Resource temporarily unavailable" is `EAGAIN`.  You can look at `man errno` or use the `errno(1)` command if installed to get that.

Comment: Per the `read(2)` man page, `EAGAIN` should only happen if the file descriptor has been opened or set non-blocking.  Is that the case?

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "no more data available".  If the writing end of the fifo has been closed, then `read()` ought to return 0, just like end-of-file.  If it hasn't been closed, then the read will block until the writer does write more data (if in blocking mode) or return -1 with `EAGAIN` if in non-blocking.  Note that unless the writing end has been closed, the OS has no way to know whether the writer intends to write more data in the future, or not, so the two cases cannot be distinguished.

Comment: That is an excellent point. Thanks. It clarifies why I am getting the same responce from OS. Briefly, at start I open what I need, and then use blocking/unblocking. Nothing is closed until end of app. Thus, using a marker is the solution. e.g. GDB always ends its response with (gdb) prompt, so you know there is no more data coming in. That was a great explanation. Thanks.